# Getting table of values from list col names in R

Tags: r

#### To recreate my problem use this code in R

```
list.1<-list(c(11L, 13L), c(9L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 25L), c(5L, 8L, 11L), c(10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 16L))
names(list.1[[1]]) <- paste("name", c("2","6"), sep = "")
names(list.1[[2]]) <- paste("name", c("2","3", "5", "6", "7", "10", "14", "15", "16"), sep = "")
names(list.1[[3]]) <- paste("name", c("4","9", "16"), sep = "")
names(list.1[[4]]) <- paste("name", c("2","3", "5", "9", "12"), sep = "")
```

#### This creates a list of names in the following way

```
[1] name2 name6 
     11    13
[2] name2  name3  name5  name6  name7 name10 name14 name15 name16 
     9     12     14     15     16     19     20     22     25
```

#### I'd like to have a data frame from the above list in this way instead

```
[1] name1 name2  name3  name4 name5  name6 name7 name8 name9 name10 name11 etc. to name16
      0    11     0      0      0     13    0      0     0     0      0

[2]   0    9      12     0     14     15    16     0     0     0      0
```

Basically, I'd like to have every category of names possible (names1-16) even if they are missing from each element of the list.

My previous command that *doesn't work* but gave me a table of just the shortened lists without the missing values was:

```
df.list1 <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(df.list1,'[',1:16)))
```

This gave me 16 columns as desired, but did not give me missing columns so I have different vector lengths in each row with NA's filling the remaining space (i.e. it stacked name2 and name6 in the first two columns where I'd like them to be in the second and sixth columns with the other columns taking values of zero).

Have some R magic to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` with `fill = TRUE` to create a single `data.table` as it would be better to store as a single dataset instead of multiple datasets with single rows in a `list`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list.1, as.data.frame.list), fill = TRUE)
```

As @Frank suggested in the comments, `rbindlist` can take a `list`

```
rbindlist(lapply(list.1, as.list), fill=TRUE)
```

---

If we really want individual `data.frame`, one option is to create the columns based on the `names` that are not there

```
lapply(list.1, function(x) {x1 <- as.data.frame.list(x)
      x1[setdiff(paste0("name", 1:16), names(x))] <- 0
      x1[paste0("name", 1:16)]})
#[[1]]
#  name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9 #name10 name11 name12 name13 name14 name15 name16
#1     0    11     0     0     0    13     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

#[[2]]
#  name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9 name10 name11 name12 name13 name14 name15 name16
#1     0     9    12     0    14    15    16     0     0     19      0      0      0     20     22     25

#[[3]]
#  name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9 name10 name11 name12 name13 name14 name15 name16
#1     0     0     0     5     0     0     0     0     8      0      0      0      0      0      0     11

#[[4]]
#  name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9 name10 name11 name12 name13 name14 name15 name16
#1     0    10    11     0    13     0     0     0    14      0      0     16      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: `rbindlist` does't need data.frames/tables, fyi: `rbindlist(lapply(list.1, as.list), fill=TRUE)`

Comment: Also, there's `dcast(rbindlist(lapply(list.1, stack), id=TRUE), .id ~ ind, value.var='values', fill = 0)` though that puts the columns in a weird order...

Comment: Works like magic and a data.table is fine for my purposes. Thanks! When I did rbindlist(lapply(list.1, as.data.frame.list), fill = TRUE) across the whole set it came in a random column order but I checked the values (they corresponded with the correct names) and used setcolorder to reorder them. Cheers!